# Clear Pepper's chash memory

Tags: video, tablet, pepper

I need to load several videos on Pepper's tablet. but after playing one or two very small videos (about 15 mgb) the tablet stop working and just shows a black screen (not animated bubbles) and I have to reboot it to show a new video.

But if I repeat one video several times (i test it 20 times) it can play the video with no stop. I think once a video loaded in pepper's cash, it can be played as much as we want but replacing a new video with the old one makes the trouble. 
Does it make sense? if yes how can I clear pepper's cash to free space for a new video? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug.

You could try calling [`ALTabletService.resetTablet()`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/altabletservice-api.html#ALTabletService::resetTablet) before loading a new one to cache.